# UITableViewCell setEditing is not called

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have `UIViewController` that contains `UITableView`. I implemented my custom edit button that toggles `setEditing:animated` for the table view. Everything works good, delete and reordering icons show up. Table view cells has custom class (subclass of `UITableViewCell`), where I override `setEditing` method to do some extra customisation when edit mode is ON.

From documentation:

> When the table view receives setEditing:animated:, it sends the same
>   message to the UITableViewCell object for each visible row.

As I understand `setEditing` method should be called for every cell, but unfortunately it does not happen. Where could be the problem? What I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake. I was overriding

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
```

but instead I should override

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```